# Ionic select ngModel whole object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel, ionic4

My code looks like that:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="current_language" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" (ionChange)="changeLanguage()">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">{{language.name}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

when I choose one of them and click "Okay" in .ts file `current_language` is exactly what I have chosen. but the problem is that I think another way of binding doesn't work. because initially `current_language` is not chosen when I enter the page.

this is my language:

```
Language{
id: number;
name: string;
flag: string;
code: string;
status: number;
```

}

so what should I do to have two way binding of `Language` object? Because I need the whole `Language` object that was chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set it to select:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Language</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="current_language">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let language of languages; let i = index" [value]="language" [selected]="i === 0"> // selects first item
              {{language.name}} 
          </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

**or** value your ngModel with one of your array's item:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Language</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="current_language">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let language of languages;" [value]="language">
              {{language.name}} 
          </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

in ts:

```
current_language = this.languages[0]; // selects first item
```

**update**:
if you are getting the current language form store:

```
ngOnInit(){
    let fromStore: Language =  {name: 'second' , id:1};
    let index: number = this.languages.findIndex(item => item.id === fromStore.id);
    this.current_language = this.languages[index];
  }
```

check [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-first-select-fco6z6).

Comment: but I get current_language from store so this.languages[0] will not be correct, nor [selected]="i === 0"

Comment: what is store? :)) you mean get it async from server?

Comment: OK now i know, you should get the get current language from store and find it in your languages array then find the index and and assign it to current_language.

Comment: @O.Shekriladze i updated the answer and demo check now.

Comment: Thank @Fateme Fazli ,  [(ngModel)]="prog"  (ionChange)="progChange(prog)"

Answer (score 1):

Use `CompareWith` to select the default. Also notice the use of `[(value)]`

In template, add:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="current_language" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" (ionChange)="changeLanguage()" [compareWith]="compareObjects">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [(value)]="language">{{language.name}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

In the component ts file, add the function:

```
compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
return o1._id === o2._id;//Compare by id
}
```

This implementation uses compare using `Id`, you can chose to use any other properties or combination of properties.

Comment: it says : Can't bind to 'compareWith' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select'.